# using directive to join two input value

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

I would like to "autofill" an input depending on other form values. "id" should be "name" + "." + "combo":

```
 <input matInput name="id" required placeholder="ID" #idValue readonly/>
 <input matInput ngModel name="name" required placeholder="NAME" autoFillId /> 
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select ngModel name="combo" required placeholder="COMBO" autoFillId >
       <mat-option value=1>Value 1</mat-option>  
       <mat-option value=2>Value 2</mat-option>  
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And this is my directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoFillId]'
})

export class AutoFillDirective {

 @Output() idValue: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
 value: string = ".";

@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
  this.value = this.value.split(".")[0] + "." + $event.target.value;
  this.idValue.emit(this.value);
}

@HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange($event) {
  this.value = $event.value + "." + this.value.split(".")[1];
  this.idValue.emit(this.value);
}

}
```

It works separatelly, I mean, if I got "undefinded.2" if changes the combo or "myName.undefined" if changes the input.

How can I do it together?

Comment: Where do you use `idValue` output?

Comment: I forgot it, editted

Comment: How is your template reference variable `#idValue` connected with `@Output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I took a little time to test and debug your code and this is what I found out:

**1) You are calling 2 different instances of your directive**

You're calling `autoFillId` in the combo and the input, so each of them will have a **different** instance of the directive. That means they both will have a different instance of `this.value` and since the value is never shared between the two instances, you'll always have only one side working.

**2) `select` triggers both input and change events**

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange($event) {
  this.value = $event.value + "." + this.value.split(".")[1];
  this.idValue.emit(this.value);
}
```

This will be triggered on clicking on the select.

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
  this.value = this.value.split(".")[0] + "." + $event.target.value;
  this.idValue.emit(this.value);
}
```

This will be triggerd on selecting an option.
That's what causing the `undefined` to appear.

There are multiple solutions to solve your problem, if you want to keep this behavior on a directive you'll have to pass the changed value to the other instance of the directive.

```
<select name="combo" required placeholder="COMBO" [autoFillId]="currentId" (idValue)="getId($event)">
       <option value=1>Value 1</option>  
       <option value=2>Value 2<option>  
<select>
```

**your.component.ts**

```
currentId = "."

getId(event) {
  this.currentId = event;
}
```

**autofill.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoFillId]'
})

export class AutoFillDirective {

  @Output() idValue: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  //This input will load the value of the ID when changed
  @Input('autoFillId') value: string;

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
    /* We need to check if the event is triggered by the input or the select
       We can do this by checking the constructor name for example.
    */
    if($event.constructor.name === 'InputEvent') {
      this.value = this.value.split(".")[0] + "." + $event.target.value;
    } else {
      this.value = $event.target.value + "." + this.value.split(".")[1];
    }
    this.idValue.emit(this.value);
  }

}
```

And here you go.
You can check the working example here : **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrvxdd)**